# Listen to className changes on an element replaced by ng-content

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection, angular-lifecycle-hooks

I need to listen to class name changes on a element being replaced by the `<ng-content>`. I have tried many ways and the only way I found for this is by using `setInterval` which I think is not a good practice. Suppose I will inject an `input` element inside the `<app-child>` component

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: `
    <app-child>
     <input type="text">
    </app-child>
  `
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() { }
}
```

And that I want to do something inside `child.component.ts` whenever the `class` attribute of the `input` change:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template: `<ng-content select="input"></ng-content>`
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  @ContentChild(HTMLInputElement) input: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    setInterval(() => {
       const { className } = this.input.nativeElement;
       console.log(className);
    }, 500);
  }
}
```

This approach manages to detect the class change but the problem with `setInterval` is that that callback will be running on background every `500` milliseconds, is there another way to detect the change?

Note: I've already tried the hook `ngAfterContentChecked` which is ran automatically after any change detection but inside I don't have access to the latest change on `this.input.nativeElement.className` as if this function was executed before the value was changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) Api

Something like this:

```
  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    this.changes = new MutationObserver((mutations: MutationRecord[]) => {
      mutations.forEach((mutation: MutationRecord) => {
        // this is called twice because the old class is removed and the new added
        console.log(
          `${mutation.attributeName} changed to ${this.input.nativeElement.classList}`
        );
      });
    });

    this.changes.observe(this.input.nativeElement, {
      attributeFilter: ['class'],
    });
  }
```

Here is a stackblitz with it running https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tz5q88?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild.component.ts

Comment: Great thank you! It's good for me, to prevent the multiple calls of the `mutations` callback I'll use a `behaviourSubject<string>` passing the `className` of the last item of `mutations` in conjuction with the `debounceTime` operator, so it'll only emit the last `className` change in a specified period of time.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code that implements debounceTime. I am not sure

```
this.callback = this.callback.bind(this);
```

is correct way to assign. But this works.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { isEmpty } from 'lodash';
import { Subject, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { debounceTime, first } from 'rxjs';

@Directive({
  selector: '.has-validation'
})
export class HasValidationDirective {
  el: any;
  formElement: any;
  observer: any;
  classNameChanged: Subject<any> = new Subject();
  subscriptions:any = [];

  constructor(el: ElementRef) {
    this.el = el;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.callback = this.callback.bind(this);
    const subscription = this.classNameChanged.pipe(debounceTime(100)).subscribe(() => {
      this.toggleClassname();
    });
    this.subscriptions.push(subscription);
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.toggleClassname();
    })
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const formElementClassNames = ['form-input', 'form-textarea', 'form-select', 'form-radio', 'form-multiselect', 'form-checkbox'];
    formElementClassNames.forEach((className) => {
      const formElement = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('.' + className)
      if (!isEmpty(formElement)) {
        this.formElement = formElement;
      }
    })
    if (isEmpty(this.formElement)) {
      const formElementClassNamesJoined = formElementClassNames.join(' (or) ');
      console.error(`class has-validation must have a form element with class name specified as ${formElementClassNamesJoined}`)
      return;
    }
    this.observer = new MutationObserver(this.callback);
    const a = this.observer.observe(this.formElement, { attributeFilter: ['class'] });
  }


  callback(mutationList: any, observer: any) {
    // Use traditional 'for loops' for IE 11
    for (const mutation of mutationList) {
      if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
       // console.log('A child node has been added or removed.');
      }
      else if (mutation.type === 'attributes') {
        // console.log(`The ${mutation.attributeName} attribute was modified.`);
        this.classNameChanged.next(null);

      }
    }
  };

  toggleClassname() {
    const validationClassnames = ['ng-valid',
      'ng-invalid',
      'ng-pending',
      'ng-pristine',
      'ng-dirty',
      'ng-untouched',
      'ng-touched'];

    validationClassnames.forEach((className) => {
      this.el.nativeElement.classList.remove(className);
      if (this.formElement.classList.contains(className)) {
        this.el.nativeElement.classList.add(className);
      }
    })
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.observer) {
      this.observer.disconnect();
    }
    this.subscriptions.forEach((subscription:Subscription)=>{
      subscription.unsubscribe();
    })
  }

}
```